# Is there an android app that turns off sound certain times of the week (like at work)?

Tags: audio, 5.1-lollipop

I know very little about android.  Is there a widget, app or other way to configure so the sound is off while I am at work (or at night).  Essentially trying to turn down the ringer while I am at work.

My wife an I both have 5.1 Android phones.  We would both like this feature.

Comment: Have you tried Interruption mode  or any automation app so far? Related: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111295?hl=en

Comment: I have not tried any automation app.  Please recommend one.  I like the idea of not having to take any action on certain times for certain days.  The info above about for 5.0 is great.  I didn't know about selecting the volume button and selecting none.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is tap the volume down button a couple of times so your phone goes into do-not-disturb mode

You can also do this by pulling down to the quick settings and tapping the do-not-disturb button there

Comment: Android Lollipop doesn't have Do not Disturb mode.

Comment: @Firelord It depends: CM12.1 does have it.

Comment: I prefer an automated system.  But the do-not-disturb button will work in the mean time.    I just didn't realize "None" button would do that.  Thank you.